# Laravel - timezone - Config null

Tags: laravel, timezone

I installed laravel-timezone as described here: https://github.com/jamesmills/laravel-timezone

also added teh configuration file, and in the configuraiton file there is this:

timezone.php

```
'lookup' => [
    'server' => [
        'REMOTE_ADDR',
    ],
    'headers' => [

    ],
],
```

After the login, the script is suposed to update the timezone automatically, but I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in the file `\vendor\jamesmills\laravel-timezone\src\Listeners\Auth\UpdateUsersTimezone.php:111`

the function is this:

```
  /**
* @return mixed
*/
private function getFromLookup()
{
    $result = null;
    foreach (config('timezone.lookup') as $type => $keys) {
        if (empty($keys)) {
            continue;
        }

        $result = $this->lookup($type, $keys);

        if (is_null($result)) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I tried to put a dd() there, and `config('timezone.lookup')` is null.. 
why does it return null, if the file exists, and a value is assigned in the file?
Is there anything I have to do to make this timezone.php accesisble?

Comment: Is your config cached?

Comment: @apokryfos yes it is..

Comment: Try clearing the config cache first

Comment: that did the trick! thank you! can you post it as answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are caching the configuration Laravel creates a file in `bootstrap/cache/config.php` with all the configuration. After this is done the individual cache files and the `.env` file **are  no longer read**.

You therefore need to clear your config cache, and I recommend to not cache it while in development. Only cache the config in production.

Just run:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you’re having issues using the package. As far as I’m aware you don’t have to publish the config for the package to work after initial install. It should pick up defaults so you should be able to install it and go! However, like others have said, if you do publish the config then please try to flush your config cache php artisan cache:clear

Thank you @apokryfos for your help on this issue.

If you have any further issues please don’t hesitate to reply.

James

Comment: thank you for your great package.. it works like a charm after cache:clear! maybe you could add it to your documentation. Also, during install I get 2 warnings about packages that should not be used, and replaced by other ones.. are you aware of that?